# Formatting output to show in the messages section in error list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'd like to print a message to the output, not just a warning/error.

For example, you can have:

```
1>C:\Example Path\Example File.cpp(1): warning EXAMPLE: here is an example warning
1>C:\Example Path\Example File.cpp(1): error EXAMPLE: here is an example error
```

These following outputs will show up in the error list window. This can be done with `#pragma message( )`. How can I have something show up as a message, not an error or warning? `info` and `message` didn't seem to work.

Comment: I think you need to explain more precisely what you are trying to achieve. Do you want your program to print something on the standard output? Or do you want to avoid the warning/error? Are you simply looking for `printf` and `std::cout`?

Comment: First of all, for which compiler, and what version of it? Secondly, *why*? What problem is it supposed to solve?

Comment: @AdrienLeravat I think he's trying to print out a "message" in his build environment when compiling code without it being a warning or error

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/BloE5QO.png Please see the following image. Sorry, english isn't my first language. The compiler is VC++. I'm using Visual Studio 2017, but the version doesn't matter as it is across all versions; I added the tag, but maybe I should've mentioned it in the question. There is no "problem", it's just so I can use the error list more effectively to communicate things that aren't errors/warnings.

Comment: You’re lucky if I’m looking for warnings when compiling (especially if I’m not a developer); I’m certainly not looking for “info”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages are broken. Build messages do not show up in the message list.

That said, it's supposed to show up if something is preceded with the "note" flag. There is not code identifier for a message, so it's just "note:"